# Thread race conditions

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

I have this algorithm that two threads run at the same time

```
n = 0

int tmp

do 10 times

    tmp = n
    n = tmp + 1
```

I know this can get 20, and 10 by each thread executing all the way to the end in sequence, and by one thread loading n into tmp, then the other finishing will result in 10.

I'm just not sure if this can get 2.

Comment: Like, what kind of pseudo language is that ? w.r.t to threads, you must first define scope of those variables ? It is not guaranteed that `n` and `tmp` will be 20 and 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that n will be >= 10 and <= 20, and that I really don't see how you could get anything < 10. But the whole thing is so *wrong*, I don't even know why I am answering :-)